# SWIFT MT message validation

Tags: message, swift-mt

I am looking for java library or a vb addin that can be used for 
 - SWIFT message syntax validation
 - Building SWIFT message from available data.
 - Retrieving the required tag/field data.

Can anybody help me in this regard??

### I have seen few of the available libraries like WIFE but all fails in catching errors if the message is not in standard format.

Pavan

Answer (score 3):

with "SWIFT message syntax validation" I guess you are speaking about getting the FIN syntax right?

If so, I have just posted an answer to another SWIFT related question on StackOverflow.

I have copy and pasted my response below again for your convenience (from here: [java-swift-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192/java-swift-library)):

---

SWIFT is releasing a "Standards Developer Kit" which includes an "MT/XML Schema Library".

From the doc: "The MT/XML Schema Library is a complete set of XML schema definitions for MT messages, and software which shows how to convert messages from an MT format to an MT XML representation and back. This approach allows XML integration between applications while the MT (FIN) format will continue to be transported over the SWIFT network."

Java source code will also be made available, again from the doc: "Working sample Java source code that converts a message in MT format to an XML instance and from an XML instance to a message in MT format."

See: https://www.swiftcommunity.net/communities/download.cfm?id=4798

This can be a great aid in dealing with FIN messages in XML syntax.

---

So, using the "Standards Developer Kit" you do not have to worry anymore about getting the FIN syntax right.

Hope it is useful for you,

Stijn.

Answer (score 0):

We use WIFE and have to do validation on the Swift tag data prior to constructing the message using WIFE.  I don't believe WIFE provides any validation.

**Update**: A Google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=swift+validation) turns up the [AnaSys](http://www.anasys.com/Services/swiftvalidationservice/) service along with a few others that look promising.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Suppose I have a message and I need to check if it is in correct format, then do u think i can use wife (5.1 version)?

Comment: I haven't done any validation using WIFE.  I don't see any mention of this in the WIFE docs.

Comment: do you have any idea of other libraries... Java or .net for this purpose??

Thanks