# SWIFT message parsing for .NET

Tags: .net, api, swift-mt

Can anyone recommend .NET APIs for SWIFT message parsing and provide pros/cons?

Something like this http://www.anasys.com/products/messageobjects/ which I found so far.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 5):

We ended up with writing our own. There were several reasons for that:

- original SWIFT messages are fixed width and well documented, which makes them easy to handle
- new SWIFT messages are XML based, even easier to handle
- we needed only to parse and produce several message types
- we could fit it into our integration framework

So, in my opinion it really depends how many different message types you need to handle. If only a handful - it would not take much to code own parser.

Comment: It seems I was not aware of The MT/XML Schema Library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192/java-swift-library

Answer (score 0):

Different banks have different file formats even if their message formats are the same but file type might be different. Some use a simple text file , other use CVS. It's best do it your online or look java open source project Wife 1.5. I am trying to convert it to .net and publish it on CodeProject but haven't had the time yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply choose any .NET XML stack to handle SWIFT messages.

This is possible due to the MT/XML libraries released by SWIFT themselves (as noted by Juliusz).

So now all SWIFT messages can be treated as pure XML! No more headaches trying to understand the intricaties of the FIN syntax!